# Running scheduled async function in background

Tags: python, asynchronous

Is there any way to run scheduled async function in background
I tried

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
async def checking():
    await print('Hello World')
scheduler.add_job(checking, 'cron', hour='02', minute='11')
```

but it says

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'checking' was never awaited self._do_submit_job(job, run_times)
>
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

And I can't use `AsyncIOScheduler()` as it doesn't run in background...

Comment: Assuming `BackgroundScheduler` comes from [Advanced Python Scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/index.html), have you tried reading the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/faq.html#why-doesn-t-the-scheduler-run-my-jobs)?

Comment: @Woodford yeah, nothing about it

Comment: Scheduler doesn't use async